# Iterate Key Value Pairs From Data-Bind Attribute

Tags: javascript

I want to iterate each key and value from data-bind attribute using javascript. Do you have some idea. Should I use some kind of `substring` and `split` after using `el.getAttribute('data-bind')`.

Here is simple example:

```
<div data-bind="innerHTML: text, style: { color: color, width: '500px', height: '500px', backgroundColor: 'green' }"></div>
```

I want to get the values from `innerHTML` and `style` keys one by one with iteration using `pure javascript`.

Comment: Only pure javascript?

Comment: Yes only pure javascript.

Comment: In the example you want to iterate over 2 key-values?

Comment: Yes innerHTML should return length of 1 values and style should return length of 4 and to iterate them.

Answer (score 1):

Convert your string into a json object. And then use key for getting value. You need to update your HTML as follows.

```
// all values of the attribute must be quoted with single quote. i.e. It should be innerHTML : 'text' not innerHTML : text
<div data-bind="innerHTML: 'text', style: { color: 'color', width: '500px', height: '500px', backgroundColor: 'green' }"></div>

var attributeValue = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].getAttribute("data-bind");
var json = JSON.stringify(eval('({' + attributeValue + '})'));
```

Then you need to parse the json object and then invoke the key values as follows,

```
var parsedJSON = JSON.parse(json);

alert(parsedJSON["innerHTML"]);
alert(parsedJSON["style"]["width"]);
```

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/c70pmztt/)

If you want to loop through the *style* attribute then try this way,

```
for(var attr in parsedJSON["style"]){
    alert(attr + " : " + parsedJSON["style"][attr]);
}
```

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/wp5dgmu5/)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the binding source code for [Knockout.js](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/binding/expressionRewriting.js). As with all things parsing, the devil is in the detail, which is why it's so complicated! You can use `parseObjectLiteral` function from `knockout.js` lib and iterate through the keys like:

```
 function enumerateProperties(str, items) {

     var n, i,
         arr = parseObjectLiteral(str);

     if (!str) { return 0; }

     for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 1) {
         if (arr[i].key) {
             n = enumerateProperties(arr[i].value, items);
             if (n == 1) {
                 items.push({
                     key: arr[i].key,
                     value: arr[i].value
                 });
             }
         }
     }

     return arr.length;
 }
```

Here is working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wfjLs9Ls/) using knockout parsing function.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit of a cheat, but who cares. :P Wrap it as an object and use `eval`. (It's not valid JSON.)

```
eval('({' + theStuffFromDataBind + '})')
```